# Aws S3 access denied issue

Tags: java

```
I am trying to access s3 bucket. I am able to do so using my local machine(i.e. from my local machine to S3 bucket), but getting access denied issue while trying to access it from EC2 instance running tomcat 8 and java 8.
```

Also when i upload the file the permissions are set for root user and if I keep my bucket as public and upload the file from EC2 the permissions are not set for the root user.

```
    public class AmazonS3UtilService {
    public static final String NAME = "amazonS3Util";
    private static String S3_SECRET = "S3_SECRET";
    private static String S3_ID = "S3_ID";
    private static String BUCKET_NAME = "S3_BUCKET";
    private static final String SUFFIX = "/";
    private static final String DEFAULT_FOLDER_PATH = "PHR/Reports/";

    @Autowired
    protected Environment props;

    private AWSCredentials awsCredentials = null;

    private AmazonS3 s3Client = null;

    private String bucketName = null;

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AmazonS3UtilService.class);

    private void prepareAWSCredentials() {

        if (awsCredentials == null) {
            log.info("Preparing AWS Credentials");
            awsCredentials = new AWSCredentials() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();

                public String getAWSSecretKey() {
                    String S3_SECRET = System.getProperty(AmazonS3UtilService.S3_SECRET);

                    if (S3_SECRET == null) {
                        S3_SECRET = System.getenv(AmazonS3UtilService.S3_SECRET);
                        if (S3_SECRET == null) {
                            S3_SECRET = props.getProperty(AmazonS3UtilService.S3_SECRET);
                        }
                    }
                    log.info("S3_SECRET ---->" + S3_SECRET);
                    return S3_SECRET;
                }

                        public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
                            String S3_ID = System.getProperty(AmazonS3UtilService.S3_ID);

                            if (S3_ID == null) {
                                S3_ID = System.getenv(AmazonS3UtilService.S3_ID);
                                if (S3_ID == null) {
                                    S3_ID = props.getProperty(AmazonS3UtilService.S3_ID);
                                }
                            }
                            log.info("S3_ID ---->" + S3_ID);
                            return S3_ID;
                        }
                    };
                }

            }

            private void prepareAmazonS3Client() {
                if (s3Client == null) {
                    log.info("Preparing S3 Client");
                    ClientConfiguration clientCfg = new ClientConfiguration();
                    clientCfg.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
                    s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, clientCfg);
                    Region region = Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(props.getProperty("s3client.region")));
                    log.info("Region ----->" + props.getProperty("s3client.region"));
                    s3Client.setRegion(region);
                }
            }

            private void prepareBucketName() {
                bucketName = System.getenv(AmazonS3UtilService.BUCKET_NAME);
                    log.info("bucketName ------>" + bucketName);
                }

            }

            private void prepare() {
                try {
                    awsCredentials = null;
                    prepareAWSCredentials();
                    prepareAmazonS3Client();
                    prepareBucketName();
                } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
                    log.error("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it "
                            + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.");
                    log.error("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage() + " HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode()
                            + " AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode() + " Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType()
                            + " Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());

                    new AmazonS3ClientException(ase, ase.getMessage());
                } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
                    log.error(ace);
                    new AmazonS3ClientException(ace, ace.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public String uploadDocument(UploadDocumentDetailDTO uploadDocumentDetail) {
                prepare();
                String tempFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                String fileURL = null;
                try {
                    File uploadFileContent = readBase64File(uploadDocumentDetail.getFileContent(), tempFileName);
                    uploadDocumentDetail.setContentType(FileContentTypeEnum.PDF);
                    String uploadFileName = getUploadFileName(uploadDocumentDetail);
                    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, uploadFileName, uploadFileContent);
                    request.putCustomRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                    request.putCustomRequestHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
                    PutObjectResult putObjectResult = s3Client.putObject(request);
                    URL url = generatePresignedUrlRequest(uploadFileName);
                    fileURL = url.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.info(LoggerException.printException(e));
                    fileURL = "";
                }

                return fileURL;
            }

            public URL generatePresignedUrlRequest(String fileURL) {
                log.info("Inside generatePresignedUrlRequest");
                java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
                long msec = expiration.getTime();
                msec += 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour.
                expiration.setTime(msec);

                GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, fileURL);
                generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET); // Default.
                generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

                URL s = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
                log.info("Url --->" + s);
                return s;
            }

            private String getUploadFileName(UploadDocumentDetailDTO uploadDocumentDetail) {
                StringBuffer uploadFileName = new StringBuffer();
                uploadFileName.append(DEFAULT_FOLDER_PATH);
                if (uploadDocumentDetail.getBeneficiaryId() != null)
                    uploadFileName.append(uploadDocumentDetail.getBeneficiaryId() + SUFFIX);

                if (uploadDocumentDetail.getDocumentType() != null)
                    uploadFileName.append(uploadDocumentDetail.getDocumentType().getName() + SUFFIX);

                // Check and create Folder
                validateAndCreateFolder(uploadFileName.toString());

                if (uploadDocumentDetail.getAssesmentId() != null)
                    uploadFileName.append(
                            uploadDocumentDetail.getAssesmentId() + "." + uploadDocumentDetail.getContentType().getName());
                else
                    uploadFileName.append(
                            uploadDocumentDetail.getDefaultFileName() + "." + uploadDocumentDetail.getContentType().getName());
                return uploadFileName.toString();
            }

            private static File readBase64File(String content, String fileName) throws Exception {
                File file = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".tmp");
                file.deleteOnExit();
                FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fileOuputStream.write(Base64.decodeBase64(content));
                fileOuputStream.close();
                return file;

            }

            public void validateAndCreateFolder(String folderName) {
                List<S3ObjectSummary> fileList = null;
                try {
                    fileList = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName, folderName).getObjectSummaries();
                } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (fileList == null || fileList.isEmpty()) {
                    // create meta-data for your folder and set content-length to 0
                    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                    metadata.setContentLength(0);
                    // create empty content
                    InputStream emptyContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
                    // create a PutObjectRequest passing the folder name suffixed by /
                    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, folderName, emptyContent, metadata);
                    // send request to S3 to create folder
                    s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
                }
            }

            /**
             * This method first deletes all the files in given folder and than the
             * folder itself
             */
        }
```

Following is the exception while access S3 from EC2 instance.

```
INFO  com.medscheme.common.util.AmazonS3UtilService  - com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 926E1213366626B9), S3 Extended Request ID: zQbb4JCalYExHZtDSv0GmWxoHrQZJUV3M+jlUiaVJY/sDxW/qoNFC8hizfangVCjweWZtOqC7/A=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1275)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:873)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:576)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:362)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:328)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:307)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3649)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3602)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:679)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:664)
    at com.medscheme.common.util.AmazonS3UtilService.validateAndCreateFolder(AmazonS3UtilService.java:222)
    at com.medscheme.common.util.AmazonS3UtilService.getUploadFileName(AmazonS3UtilService.java:200)
    at com.medscheme.common.util.AmazonS3UtilService.uploadDocument(AmazonS3UtilService.java:166)
    at com.medscheme.service.impl.ReportsServiceImpl.getReport(ReportsServiceImpl.java:133)
    at com.medscheme.service.impl.ReportsServiceImpl.getReport(ReportsServiceImpl.java:1)
    at com.medscheme.controller.ReportsController.getWellnessReportDetails(ReportsController.java:69)
```

Comment: How are you trying to access your bucket? IAM or logging into AWS?

Comment: To get an answer you need to (1) show your exact steps, and (2) show the exact error message. Please edit your question with these, indenting the commands and error by 4 spaces so that it will appear as code.

Comment: I am trying it using jave code (AmazonS3)

Comment: I see that you log the keys; have you verified that those keys are associated with a user/role that can access the bucket?

Comment: Also, rather than writing your own code to retrieve credentials, I recommend using [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html). Among other things, this will allow you to assign a role to your EC2 instance and grant permissions to that role rather than specific users.

Comment: Where can I confirm the keys association with user/role.

Comment: If you log the keys, then running "`aws iam get-user`" with those keys should tell you what you need to know. If that doesn't work, it's actually rather painful (or I don't know the best way): "`aws iam list-users`" will give you all your users, and then you need to run "`list-access-keys`" for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using BasicAWSCredentials class instead of AWSCredentials while creating the amazon client.
The problem was only with EC2 instance.
Does anybody know what was going wrong on EC2.